# How to print all tab in one page in with single click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I print all information in every tabs with one single click `print` button. Currently its only printing the page viewed only. I want to print every tab in one page. How do I fix and do that ?  The download button is sit on the menu 3 tabs

I also wants to achieve it to sit vertically. Any idea on how to do that ?

```js
$("#downloadPdf").click(function() {
  $('#tabs a[href="#homepage"]').tab('show');
  $('#tabs a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
  $('#tabs a[href="#info"]').tab('show');
  $('#tabs a[href="#form"]').tab('show');
  // Print the page
  window.print();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homepage">Terms & Condition</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Form</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#form">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="homepage" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
        <span style="font-size: 80%;"><i>Please read the terms and condition first</i></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="reg"> Please tick this if u have read and understand everything </label>
      </div>
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="info" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="form" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        <br>
        <p> <button type="button" id="downloadPdf" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download">Download</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.print()` prints what you see. Get your page to render in the browser as you would want it to print. Note that `.tab()` is likely designed to automatically hide the tabs. I suspect adding the class `active` to each tab content div would show each tab (but might break the tab's user interaction).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in you own page - it does not work here due to sandboxing

```
$("#downloadPdf").click(function() {
  const html = $('.container').find('.tab-content').map(function() { return $(this).html() }).get().join('<hr/>')
  console.log(html)
  const w = window.open('','newpage')
  w.document.write(html)
  w.document.close()
  w.print();
});
```